# FileSystem monitor on a remote server with Python watchdog

Tags: python-3.x, server, remote-server, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am creating a Filesystem monitor for a windows server that checks if files are created, modified, deleted and writes it into a csv file. My problem is that the user i am getting is the server administrator, how can i get the remote user accessing the server? I have my codebelow:

```
def on_deleted(event):
    d = datetime.datetime.today()
    if os.environ.get("REMOTE_USER") is not None:
        user=os.environ.get("REMOTE_USER")
    else:
        user=getpass.getuser()
    with open(report,'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([Config["Action_Delete"], user, event.src_path, d.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")])
    print(f"{event.src_path} has been deleted", "by:", user)

def on_modified(event):
    d = datetime.datetime.today()
    if os.environ.get("REMOTE_USER") is not None:
        user=os.environ.get("REMOTE_USER")
    else:
        user=getpass.getuser()
    with open(report, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([Config["Action_Modify"], user, event.src_path, d.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")])
    print(f"{event.src_path} has been modified by: ", user)

def on_moved(event):
    d = datetime.datetime.today()
    if os.environ.get("REMOTE_USER") is not None:
        user=os.environ.get("REMOTE_USER")
    else:
        user=getpass.getuser()
    with open(report, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([Config["Action_Move"], user, f"moved {event.src_path} to {event.dest_path}", d.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")])
    print(f"moved {event.src_path} to {event.dest_path}", user)


def CreateObserver(my_event_handler, path, recursive):
    print("start observer for: ", path)
    my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=recursive)
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
    my_observer.join()
```

Comment: These are functions, not a full working bit of code.

Comment: Please see it here: https://github.com/romeo0214/FileSystemMonitor